# Console log response from ajax returns a full page instead of a string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am tring to filter the rows from a table based on what is chosen in a select tag.

I created a function that is triggerd when the select option is changed. It saves the information from the table in a bidimensional array .
This is how is looks.

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPTOz.png)

Now I am tring to get the array from jquery to php using ajax and post method , but i can't return anything on succes even if the target file is empty .

If i console.log the response it shows this

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ufD.png)

The code below

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function sortare() {
    var optiuneSortare = $('#protopopiat option:selected').text(); //get the chosen option
    var dateGenerale = new Array(); //the array in which i store the text from the table
    $("tr").each(function() {
      var date = new Array();
      var $id = $(this).find('th');
      var $valoareId = $id.html();
      date.push($valoareId);

      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        var $nume = $(this).attr('data-head');
        var $valoare = $(this).html();
        if ($nume != undefined) {
          date.push($valoare);
        } else {
          date.push($valoare);
        }
      });
      dateGenerale.push(date);
    });
    console.log(dateGenerale);// this console.log return an array as it should

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'sortare.php',
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
        tabel: dateGenerale,
        optiune: optiuneSortare
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);// this console.log return the whole page
      }
    })
  } < /script>
```

```html
<tr>
  <th class="check-column" scope="row">
    <input id="cb-select-60" type="checkbox" name="del_id[]" value="60">
  </th>
  <td data-head="Nume">-</td>
  <td data-head="Prenume">-</td>
  <td data-head="Parohia">Sf. Ioan Domnesc, Bicaz Oras I</td>
  <td data-head="Hram">-</td>
  <td data-head="Protopopiat">Protopopiatul Piatra Neamț</td>
  <td data-head="Judetul">Neamt</td>
  <td data-head="Localitate">-</td>
  <td data-head="Strada">-</td>
  <td data-head="Nr. Strada">-</td>
  <td data-head="Telefon">0767000000</td>
  <td data-head="Email"></td>
  <td data-head="Ruta pelerinaj">Israel</td>
  <td data-head="Data inceput">13.10.2015</td>
  <td data-head="Data sfarsit">20.10.2015</td>
  <td data-head="Numar Pelerini"></td>
  <td data-head="Prestator"></td>
  <td data-head="Ghid">Pr. Paroh</td>
  <td data-head="IP-up aplicantului">94.177.46.1</td>
  <td data-head="Data aplicarii">2016-10-17 11:56:32</td>
  <td data-head="Nume Cont">5</td>
  <td><a data-rid="60" href="#TB_inline?width=600&amp;height=550&amp;inlineId=cf7d-modal-edit-value" class="thickbox cf7d-edit-value">Editează</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```html
<?php
$tabel2 = $_POST['tabel'];
$termen = $_POST['optiune'];
echo "test";
?>
```

I have never encoutered this problem .
Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: AJAX *always* returns everything. That is expected behavior.

Comment: How can i return as response from ajax the array that I am sending?

Comment: You have to parse the response for the results you want.

Comment: Can you to a little more specific?

Comment: How much more specific do you want me to be?

Comment: You meant parse the javascript array in php. Now i understand . Thank You